# Setup for Reverse Proxy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, reverse-proxy

I need to set up a reverse proxy that will forward the request to the correct application server. For example, there are two application servers running in the background. One server runs Rails while the other runs Django. If a request comes into my reverse proxy, it will direct that request to the Rails app server. If the Rails app server is unable to serve that request because it does not have support for that request, the Rails app server will return a 404 to the reverse proxy, the reverse proxy will direct the request to the Django app server (which should be the correct one).

Does anyone know a good setup for this stack or a good candidate for this reverse proxy? Something Ruby related will be good but does not have to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
server {
    Location / {
        error_page 404 /django$request_uri;

        rewrite ^/django_specific_url_1$ /django$request_uri? last;
        rewrite ^/django_specific_url_2$ /django$request_uri? last;
        ...
        rewrite ^/django_specific_url_n$ /django$request_uri? last;

        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:ruby_port;
    }

    Location /django {
        internal;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:django_port$request_uri;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have another question using the same scenario but with an additional condition added. How do you get it so that it would always pass the request to server #2 by default if it matches a certain set of URLs? Thanks!

Comment: I have amended the question to address your new query. Note that when you have follow on items that introduce new conditions, you really should make a new and separate query for these.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Pretty much what I need!

Answer (score 1):

I use Squid for my reverse proxy. Works great. http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/ReverseProxy